# history.push not redirecting to an external URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a function that runs when a button is clicked. I want to direct the user to an external site. I can't seem to do it with history.push as that appends the site to localholst ie http://localhost:8080/EXTERNALSITE

I am using RR v5

The code below works, but how can I use react router?

```
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (foo) {
      window.location.replace(EXTERNALSITE); // how to use RR here?
    } else if (userToken) {
      history.push('/home');
    } else {
      logout();
    }
  };
```

Comment: I would like to use react router

Comment: did you initialize `history` like so `const history = useHistory();`

Comment: Yep. Using history appends the url and doesn’t re-direct

Comment: show us how you did initialize your hook?

Comment: const history = useHistory();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to open an external link with react-router. However, I think it makes sense because react-router is used to handle the internal links of your app, not the external links.

So, how to navigate to an external link? In your context, I suppose we can use window.location.href

```
function openExternalLink(link) {
  window.location.replace(link);
}
```

By setting a new value to location.href, the old link is replaced by the new link (user cannot navigate back to the old link). If you don't want this behavior, you can use `window.location.href = link` instead.

For more advance usages, please [check the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).